# Spring shutdown on start up

Tags: spring, javafx

Below is what I get
Audit4j:INFO Initializing Audit4j...
Audit4j:INFO Loading Configurations...
Audit4j:INFO Validating Configurations...
Audit4j:INFO Initializing Handlers...
Audit4j:INFO org.audit4j.core.handler.ConsoleAuditHandler Initialized.
Audit4j:INFO org.audit4j.core.handler.file.FileAuditHandler Initialized.
Audit4j:INFO Initializing Layout...
Audit4j:INFO org.audit4j.core.layout.SimpleLayout Initialized.
Audit4j:INFO Initializing Streams...
Audit4j:INFO Audit Streams Initialized.
Audit4j:INFO Executing Schedulers...
Audit4j:INFO Audit4j initialized. Total time: 651ms
Exception in Application start method
2017-11-14 12:36:33.599  INFO 4068 --- [lication Thread] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1318c18e: startup date [Tue Nov 14 12:35:49 EAT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-11-14 12:36:33.602  INFO 4068 --- [lication Thread] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown

Process finished with exit code 0

Kindly assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean your project once . And restart it . The error seems like spring is not picking up some inbuilt class .